# Why do I keep getting monthly charges after cancelling?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I cancelled my UbuntuOne acct on May 11, 2011 but I've continued to be charged $3.99 in both June and July?  How do I stop this and how do I get my $8 back??

Comment: Account support for Ubuntu One is here: https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 2):

You would need to contact Ubuntu One support for that. Fill out the form on this page
https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact/ and select the "I have a billing question" from the drop down box